# Django filter on values of child objects

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have the following (simplified) data model:

```
class Article(Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=128)

class Attribute(Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=128)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='attributes')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

An example usage would be an article with an attribute attached to it with `type="brand"` and `value="Nike"`. Now I want to write an API which can get all articles with a certain brand, but I can't seem to write the filter for it. This is what I have so far:

```
class PhotobookFilter(df.FilterSet):
    brand = df.CharFilter(method='filter_brand')

    class Meta:
        model = Article

    def filter_brand(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter('order__attributes')

class PhotobookViewSet(AbstractOrderWriterViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticlePhotobookSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = PhotobookFilter
```

The line with `queryset.filter` is obviously not correct yet. I need to create a filter here that returns all articles that contain an attribute with `type="brand"` and `value=value`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to condense both lookups (`type` and `value` of `Attribute`) into one filter? Why not allow filtering on both fields separately?

E.g.

```
class PhotobookFilter(df.FilterSet):
    type = df.CharFilter(method='filter_type')
    value = df.CharFilter(method='filter_value')

    class Meta:
        model = Article

    def filter_type(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(**{'attributes__type': value}) 

    def filter_value(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(**{'attributes__value': value})
```

And now a query like `?type=brand&value=Nike` should work.

Obviously you could condense both conditions into one filter and for example hard code the band part:

```
class PhotobookFilter(df.FilterSet):
    brand = df.CharFilter(method='filter_brand')

    def filter_brand(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(**{'attributes__type': 'brand', 'attributes__value': value})
```

But keeping them separate feels way more flexible.

Comment: This doesn't work, since there is no field on `Article` called `attribute`. It returns the error: `Relation fields do not support nested lookups`. There is a field called `attributes` and I need to filter all articles of which at least one attribute exists with this type-value combination. PS Separating the two makes it harder, since I also need to filter on another type-value combination, while on the hand, the types that I need this for are predefined.

Comment: Okay, I didn't spot the `related_name` on your field. And yeah, if you feel like it, you can obviously hard code parts of the filtering (see the updated example). Hard to guess what exactly makes sense without knowing all requirements. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could also filter in reverse like this:

```
class PhotobookFilter(df.FilterSet):
    brand = df.CharFilter(method='filter_brand')

    class Meta:
        model = Article

    def filter_brand(self, queryset, name, value):
        articles = Attribute.objects.filter(type="brand", value=value).values_list('article_id', flat=True)
        return queryset.filter(id__in=articles)
```

This will create subquery for `Attribute`, which will still be one sql request in the end

Answer (score 0):

Use search_fields .For correct result rename your 'type' attribute name http://www.codesend.com/view/09ca65d42248fe1d89d07ce151f4f050/

Comment: The search fields are very handy if the fields `type` and `value` would be defined in the model in which I am querying (`Article` in this case), but in this particular case, these fields are not defined in `Article`, but in `Attribute`, and I have a list of them in the field `attributes` in the model `Article`.